How to resolve the MQTT error in the Electron Application?
In the simple Electron@29.2.0 application, I'm using mqtt@5.5.0 and getting this error -
renderer.js: Uncaught TypeError: client.on is not a function

renderer.js file -
  const topic = 'test/test';
  
  const brokerUrl = "ws://host:15675"
  const options = {
  clientId: clientId,
  username: username, 
  password: password,
  };

const client =  mqtt.connect(brokerUrl, options);

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('Connected to MQTT broker');
  
  client.subscribe(topic, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Subscribed to topic:', topic);
    } else {
      console.error('Subscription error:', err);
    }
  });
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log('Received message:', message.toString());
});

client.on('error', function (error) {
  console.error('MQTT error:', error);
});

preload.js file -
const mqtt = require('mqtt');

const { contextBridge } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('mqtt', mqtt)

In the main.js file I've set the webPreferences value like this -
webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: true,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }

